# NSTimer across multiple views

Tags: iphone

I got a NSTimer that I start in a view controller but I want it to continue run when switching between views.

How can I?

Comment: Create it one place, reference it from the other, just like you'd do with any other object.

Comment: why not letting it run in the view controller which it belongs to and navigate to the new view controller?
E.g. VC1--> timerStart (let it running here) --> navigate to new view conntroller --> VC2 --> start another timer here and let it work  in VC2...

Answer (score 0):

Put it in some common class like app delegate. Just pass the value of it in each class using delegate variable of the class.

Comment: In the above link an object is taken. you need to use your timer object.

Answer (score 0):

Create a singleton method so you can call it from any class